# how to auto start openvpn (client) on ubuntu 12.04 cli?

Tags: ubuntu, openvpn

I have an *.ovpn file that works if I type in

```
sudo openvpn client.ovpn
```

Now I would like to start up openvpn when I boot the computer. It's a headless version of ubuntu - if that matters - 12.04 64bit.

I copied filename.ovpn to /etc/openvpn but it's not starting, even if I run

```
service openvpn start
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 20):

On Ubuntu any VPN configuration you place in a file named `/etc/openvpn/$NAME.conf` will be automatically started.

So, all you have to do is copy your `client.ovpn` to `/etc/openvpn/client.conf`.  I suggest you also use absolute paths in your `client.conf` for any keys, scripts and so on.

Of course, you might want to double check the `/etc/default/openvpn` file.  By default it will autostart all VPNs, but the `AUTOSTART` value could have been changed to `none`, or to be a list of the specific configurations you want automatically started.

Comment: I tried that. All values were commented out and the documentation stated that the default was `all`.

Answer (score 10):

For **Debian OS**

1. Place your configuration file into /etc/openvpn, for example `/etc/openvpn/client.conf`.
2. Prefix/comment out lines starting with "down" and "up" (`#down` and `#up`) - or delete them
   (these are calling external script) from `client.conf`
3. Reload openvpn configuration

   ```
   /etc/init.d/openvpn reload /etc/openvpn/client.conf
   ```
4. Check with

   ```
   ifconfig
   ```

   Do you see tun0 interface? Does it have IP assigned? Great.
5. Remember the IP, reboot and try to connect.

Comment: Also see https://wiki.debian.org/OpenVPN

Comment: Perfect for my Raspberry Pi

Answer (score 9):

The client config must have the extension `.conf` and not `.ovpn`. Changing `client.ovpn` to `client.conf` in `/etc/openvpn` should work

Answer (score 1):

It would be nice to have a un hacker way of doing it, but this will have to do for now.

1) Create file  myopenvpn in  /etc/init/

```
nano /etc/init/myopenvpn
```

2) Insert into myopenvpn and save:

```
# OpenVPN autostart on boot upstart job

start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [!2345]

respawn

exec /usr/sbin/openvpn --status /var/run/openvpn.client.status 10 --cd /etc/openvpn --config /etc/openvpn/client.conf --syslog openvpn
```

SOURCE: http://www.hackerway.ch/2012/12/11/how-to-auto-start-openvpn-client-in-debian-6-and-ubuntu-12-04/#comment-79

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to put this information inside the initialization scripting for openvpn in /etc/init.d.  AND aqd appropriate symlinks to the appropriate run level based /etc/rc.d files so that it starts and stops.

Answer (score 0):

I did it on a CentOS box with the following command inserted into /etc/rc.local:

`openvpn --config /path/to/file.ovpn &`

The commands in that file are executed after every multi-user runlevel finishes booting and unlike adding it to a startup script it will not slow down your boot if the VPN takes long to setup, but some people would call this a hack.

Comment: This isn't the Right Way to handle this, especially since Debian already has an initscript which does this.

Comment: That's why I added that some people consider this a hack. This is not elegant but does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Note that for 16.04 onward you'll need [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/386308/220350):

```
systemctl start openvpn@server.service
```